# Unable to call Servlet on button click

Tags: java, servlets

I am working on a simple example of servelt in which on vbutton click I am writing some message on browser window:

I have done following things:

```
web.xml
<web-app .... >
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>


LoginServlet.java
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

LeaderConnection connection = null;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("<h1>" + "Hello" + "</h1>");
}

}


login.html
<body>
<p> This is login Page</p>

        <form action = "/LoginServlet" method = "GET">
        <input type = "submit" />

        </form>
</body>
```

When I run project on tomcat server, I am getting login page content...but when I click on button and request for servlet it's giving following message:

```
 HTTP Status 404 - /LoginServlet
 Requested resource not available
```

Why is it happening?

Comment: yeah you prob want <form action = "/ProjectName/LoginServlet" method = "GET">

Comment: yeah...it's working. why so? Why can't i use only /LoginServlet. What should I do to use it. Please answer

Comment: /Loginservlet would belong to your root webapps application.  Under Tomcat there is a away to set up a webapp to be your root webapp

Answer (score 0):

map servlet in web.xml (inside web-app tag) like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```